# passing json data downloaded using volley between activities

Tags: android, android-intent, android-volley

i am trying to pass data loaded into my listview with volley.i know how to pass images and text through activities but not json data.It may be a duplicate question but i wasnt helped with the other responses.
Below is my activity code:

```js
public class Movies extends ActionBarActivity{
 // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
 
    // Movies json url
    private static final String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.event);
 
     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

 Intent newActivity2=new Intent();
 setResult(RESULT_OK, newActivity2);
    
 listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    // changing action bar color
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));

    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    hidePDialog();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Movie movie = new Movie();
                            movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                            movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                            movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                    .doubleValue());
                            movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                            // Genre is json array
                            JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                            ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                            }
                            movie.setGenre(genre);

                            // adding movie to movies array
                            movieList.add(movie);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                 if (error instanceof NoConnectionError){
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Bummer..There's No Internet connection!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }};
            });

    // Adding request to request queue
ParseApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    hidePDialog();
}

private void hidePDialog() {
    if (pDialog != null) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
        pDialog = null;
    }
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){ 

     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                             int position, long id) { 
      
      Intent intent = new Intent(Movies.this, Detail.class);     
         startActivity(intent);
     }
     });}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}



    }
```

I am supposed to implement this code snippet when passing the param:

```js
intent.putExtra("json",jsonobj.toString());
```

and on my second activity;

```js
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(getIntent().getStringExtra("json")
```

But i dont get what to replace "json",jsonobj.toString() with from my own activity code.please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have two options here: 1) pass on the json as-is (that is: as a string) and parse it again on the receiving end (the second activity). 2) make your `Movie` class `Parcelable` (or `Serializable`) and pass on the data as Java objects to the second activity. By the way, the equivalent of `jsonobj.toString()` would be `obj.toString()` in your case.

Comment: @MH.i'd go with the first option,where i get to inflate the json ,however i'm getting error mark on `obj` ,it cannot be resolved.Whats the problem?is there some code missing?

Comment: You get the json string in the `onResponse()` method, so if you want to hang onto it, that's where you'll have to assign it to i.e. a member variable which you can then access later on (when you create the `Intent`).

Comment: @MH.yes yes,thats true.Now i am wondering if im inflating the view right in my second activity.`JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(getIntent().getStringExtra("json"));
  Movie movie = new Movie();
     movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
     movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
     movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
             .doubleValue());
     movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));
 `

Comment: I you still haven't figured things out, I'd suggest you add some breakpoints to see where the expected flow breaks. Unfortunately, the question in your last comment isn't just a simple yes or no without the project right in front of me. It sounds like you're nearly there though, so it's probably just a minor mistake somewhere.

Comment: @MH.check this sample project.It is the one i used to base my application with some twerks.(http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/) I am still stuck at this imagine.I know i'm close enough but i cant find out where i'm missing it.Check it out please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to figure it out and passed the title.The image is still underway.I'm jus doing this to help someone who was stuck like me.This will jus give you  the clue.
insert this before onCreate():

```js
 private static String Title="title";
```

Then in the onClick()

```
String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title))
                .getText().toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Movies.this, Detail.class);    
        intent.putExtra(Title, name);
        startActivity(intent);
```

And in the second activity,retrieve it a such:

```
Intent i=getIntent();
String name = i.getStringExtra(Title);

TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);

lblName.setText(name);}
```

After you have placed the following before onCreate():

```
    private static String Title="title";
```

Thanks guys for all the help.